# C# Parsing JSON object from api request

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Heys guys, so I am using Bing's maps api for my WPF application. On an API call of a specific city I get this response:

```
{
"authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
"brandLogoUri": "http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png",
"copyright": "Copyright © 2019 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
"resourceSets": [{
    "estimatedTotal": 1,
    "resources": [{
        "__type": "Autosuggest:http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/search\/local\/ws\/rest\/v1",
        "value": [{
            "__type": "Place",
            "address": {
                "countryRegion": "Netherlands",
                "adminDistrict": "Overijssel",
                "adminDistrict2": "Zwolle",
                "countryRegionIso2": "NL",
                "formattedAddress": "Zwolle, Overijssel"
            }
        }, {
            "__type": "Address",
            "address": {
                "countryRegion": "Netherlands",
                "locality": "Oldenzaal",
                "adminDistrict": "Overijssel",
                "adminDistrict2": "Gemeente Oldenzaal",
                "countryRegionIso2": "NL",
                "houseNumber": "",
                "postalCode": "7575",
                "addressLine": "Zwollestraat",
                "streetName": "Zwollestraat",
                "formattedAddress": "Zwollestraat, 7575 Oldenzaal"
            }
        }, {
            "__type": "Address",
            "address": {
                "countryRegion": "Netherlands",
                "locality": "Heerlen",
                "adminDistrict": "Limburg",
                "adminDistrict2": "Gemeente Heerlen",
                "countryRegionIso2": "NL",
                "houseNumber": "",
                "postalCode": "6415",
                "addressLine": "Zwollestraat",
                "streetName": "Zwollestraat",
                "formattedAddress": "Zwollestraat, 6415 Heerlen"
            }
        }, {
            "__type": "Address",
            "address": {
                "countryRegion": "Netherlands",
                "locality": "Gouda",
                "adminDistrict": "South Holland",
                "adminDistrict2": "Gemeente Gouda",
                "countryRegionIso2": "NL",
                "houseNumber": "",
                "postalCode": "2803",
                "addressLine": "Zwolleweg",
                "streetName": "Zwolleweg",
                "formattedAddress": "Zwolleweg, 2803 Gouda"
            }
        }, {
            "__type": "Address",
            "address": {
                "countryRegion": "Netherlands",
                "locality": "Almere",
                "adminDistrict": "Flevoland",
                "countryRegionIso2": "NL",
                "houseNumber": "",
                "postalCode": "1324",
                "addressLine": "Zwolleweg",
                "streetName": "Zwolleweg",
                "formattedAddress": "Zwolleweg, 1324 Almere"
            }
        }, {
            "__type": "Address",
            "address": {
                "countryRegion": "Netherlands",
                "locality": "Barneveld",
                "adminDistrict": "Gelderland",
                "adminDistrict2": "Gemeente Barneveld",
                "countryRegionIso2": "NL",
                "houseNumber": "",
                "postalCode": "3771",
                "addressLine": "Zwolleweg",
                "streetName": "Zwolleweg",
                "formattedAddress": "Zwolleweg, 3771 Barneveld"
            }
        }, {
            "__type": "Address",
            "address": {
                "countryRegion": "Netherlands",
                "locality": "’s-Hertogenbosch",
                "adminDistrict": "North Brabant",
                "adminDistrict2": "'s-Hertogenbosch",
                "countryRegionIso2": "NL",
                "houseNumber": "",
                "addressLine": "Zwollestraat",
                "streetName": "Zwollestraat",
                "formattedAddress": "Zwollestraat ’s-Hertogenbosch"
            }
        }]
    }]
}],
"statusCode": 200,
"statusDescription": "OK",
"traceId": "609ec284801a4ecba585123a8d2be873|DU00000D72|0.0.0.1"
}
```

I want all the addresses in like a list or an array, but that's for later. I want the `formattedAddress` specifically. This is the code I currently have but I keep getting this error:

> " System.NullReferenceException: "The object reference is not set to
>   an instance of an object."".

My Code:

```
        async static void Autosuggest(string address)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "heheprivate");

        string uri = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Autosuggest?query=" + address + "&countryFilter=NL&key=heheprivate";

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

        var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        ResourceSet rs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResourceSet>(contentString);

        //var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Address>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        MessageBox.Show(rs?.resources[0]?.value[0]?.address?.formattedAddress);
    }
```

The classes:

```
public class Address
{
    public string countryRegion { get; set; }
    public string locality { get; set; }
    public string adminDistrict { get; set; }
    public string adminDistrict2 { get; set; }
    public string countryRegionIso2 { get; set; }
    public string formattedAddress { get; set; }
    public string houseNumber { get; set; }
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
    public string addressLine { get; set; }
    public string streetName { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public string __type { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
}

public class Resource
{
    public string __type { get; set; }
    public List<Value> value { get; set; }
}

public class ResourceSet
{
    public int estimatedTotal { get; set; }
    public List<Resource> resources { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string authenticationResultCode { get; set; }
    public string brandLogoUri { get; set; }
    public string copyright { get; set; }
    public List<ResourceSet> resourceSets { get; set; }
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public string statusDescription { get; set; }
    public string traceId { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Where* in this code does the error occur?

Comment: @ScottHunter oops my bad, here MessageBox.Show(rs?.resources[0]?.value[0]?.address?.formattedAddress);

Comment: Have you tried `rs[0]?.`...?

Comment: @ScottHunter That's not possible? rs(ResourceSet) is a class, I can't say like rs[0]? Or am I doing something wrong

Comment: should be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(contentString)`

Comment: @peinearydevelopment oh wow.. this fixed it, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to deserialize your json string to wrong object, you need to deserialize it first to your RootObject that contains your ResourceSet object that you want

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
async static void Autosuggest(string address)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "heheprivate");

    string uri = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Autosuggest?query=" + address + "&countryFilter=NL&key=heheprivate";

    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

    var results = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Address>>();

    //now the 'results' is supposed to have the list of addresses from which
    //you can extract whatever you need
    //I don't promise it will work but you can try it
}
```